# Django has no Attribute 'HiddenInput'

Tags: python, django, forms, django-forms, hidden-field

I am getting the error `module 'django.forms.forms' has no attribute 'HiddenInput'` on the following code:

```
from django.forms import ModelForm, forms

from comments.models import Comment


class CommentForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ['video', 'text']
        widgets = {'video': forms.HiddenInput(),
                   'text': forms.TextArea()}
```

Does anyone know what could be causing this? I looked it up in the documentation, and HiddenInput() should be valid (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/forms/widgets/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have incorrect import, change import to this:

```
from django import forms
```

and update form's base class:

```
class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ['video', 'text']
        widgets = {'video': forms.HiddenInput(),
                   'text': forms.Textarea()}
```

Comment: I tried changing it to this, but it can't seem to find TextArea() now

Comment: @Oblivionkey3 it should be `Textarea` not `TextArea`.

Answer (score 0):

Inherit with `forms.ModelForm`

```
class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ('video', 'text')
        widgets = {'video': forms.HiddenInput(),
                    'text': forms.Textarea() }
```

Comment: We don't need to import `HiddenInput` in this way( `from django.forms.widgets import HiddenInput`). It is availabe through `from django import forms ` then `forms.HiddenInput`. (Check [this](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/__init__.py))

Comment: @ABDULNIYASPM Changed